# Reload ~/.bash_profile from inside a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I wrote a shell script that needs to reload `~/.bash_profile`, but it's not working. Here is the code.

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/.bin"' >> ~/.profile
mkdir ~/.bin
cp passwrdgen ~/.bin
chmod +x ~/.bin/passwrdgen
. ~/.profile
echo Done!
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Are you expecting PATH to be altered outside this script or something?

Comment: Also, `~/.profile` is not the same as `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

As thrig points out, are you expecting PATH to be altered outside the subshell in which the script is executed?

That is not going to work. When you export variables you do so **for the current shell only**.

Your script seems fine, try by adding a line that prints PATH at the bottom of it to make sure:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/.bin"' >> ~/.profile
mkdir ~/.bin
cp passwrdgen ~/.bin
chmod +x ~/.bin/passwrdgen
. ~/.profile
echo "$PATH"
echo Done!
```